# Finding it impossible to boot Windows after deleting GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-10

I tried to install Qubes OS, but it doesn't work on my HP (freezing at network setup).

So I used a bootable USB and with the prompt command deleted GRUB. Since then when I run my PC, this message "missing operating system" appears.

I am stuck; my hdd still has C: Windows and partition system.

What should I do to get Windows to boot?

Answer (score 1):

If your Windows is installed in EFI mode, as is likely if the computer came with Windows 8 or later pre-installed, you should be able to recover as follows:

1. Starting with the computer powered off, turn it on.
2. Hit the keystroke to enter the computer's built-in boot manager. This is the tricky part of the procedure, since this key is not standardized. If you're lucky, it will be prompted on the screen (probably just for a second or two) or mentioned in the manual. If not, try some common possibilities: A function key (usually something in the range of F8 to F12), Esc, or Enter. You may have used this keystroke to tell the computer to boot the Linux installer. You may need to repeat steps 1 and 2 several times before you find the right key.
3. Once the built-in boot manager is open, select the option to boot Windows.
4. In Windows, download and install [EasyUEFI.](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html)
5. Open EasyUEFI and use it to adjust the boot order, putting Windows first.

Answer (score 0):

You have to boot your Windows DVD / USB, then go to "Troubleshoot" -> "Command Prompt" and run:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```

in order to fix your Windows loader.

Comment: i have tried this already but it's doesn't work, when i tape " bootrec /fixmbr a command line say the operation is successfully  then i switch off the pc when run again the missing operating systeme appears again :/

Comment: @aurz That is because this answer is applicable to old BIOS only. Ignore a try the suggestions in the other answer.